# Ubuntu on Windows closes/crashes as soon as it opens

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I type Ubuntu in my Windows Search and open it, it opens and closes right after.

Also tried running it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then `bash`, but the same result.

When I run `ubuntu` in command prompt, an error message is displayed:

```
Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature the legacy console must be disabled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just disabled Legacy Console in properties of Command Prompt.